# Javascript video doesnt work on ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

The Issue:
my video doesn't display on ie11 and i would like to make it working , do some one has an elegant solution?

The list of errors i get from internet explorer 11 (ie11) is :

```
https security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/unknownprotocol.htm 
https security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTamplate.css
and so on..
```

the same code works on firefox , opera , chrome, safari and so on..

```
    (function () {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = "video.mp4";
    iframe.width = "${width}";
    iframe.height = "${height}";
    iframe.marginHeight = "0";
    iframe.marginWidth = "0";
    iframe.frameBorder = "0";
    iframe.scroling = "no";
    document.getElementById("${someElementId}").appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

Comment: This could potentially be an issue with the headers of the server. Can you confirm if you've set `X-Frame-Options` to `ORIGIN` if you're self-hosting the content?

Comment: yes  i set the header "X-Frame-Options" to "ORIGIN"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a video javascript library such as http://videojs.com. The library ensures that your code will run on a wide variety of devices by making sure even old browsers like IE6+ to run a flash applet to run the videos.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video class="video-js" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```